# android jsoup gets only one image src and i cant figure out why

Tags: java, android, image, jsoup

i'm new in android world. Im using Jsoup to collect image links from a google images however i only get the first image link (google logo)
now, ive tried everything and read https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links
but nothing seems to work, ive changed the userAgent,selector, different urls but... anyway! anyone knows where i got something stupid? thanks alot

```
new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        Document doc;
                    try {
                            String myurl =myURL;

                                doc = Jsoup.connect(myurl)
                            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1)      AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36")
                            .get();
                            Elements images = doc.select("[src]");
                            for (Element image : images)
                                if (image.tagName().equals("img"))
                        {
                            imgSrc= image.attr("abs:src");
                        }

                        runOnUiThread( new Runnable()
                        {
                            public void run()
                            {
                                HowToImport.setText(imgSrc);
                            }
                        });

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of searching i found out that i am getting all the image links but i use the last one only. So to get use the others all i needed was:

```
 Elements images = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
 Element first= images.get(1); // this line gives me the 1st element
 Element second= images.get(2); // this line gives me the 2nd element
```

and also i came up with the fact that i cant extract images from google images using Jsoup, i only get the url of the thumbnail and not the actual image url and therefore the image i get is super small and blurry.. btw correct me if im wrong! :)